# expandable collapsable DIV list

Tags: jquery

I have this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nel_mo/gad27q4b/)** which Ive been working on

If you expan the list, it works great, but
if you collapse the list, the contend flashes up on the right of the grid.

How can I stop this from happening?

Here is a snippet of the Jquery code

```
$(".header").click(function () {
    $header = $(this);
    //getting the next element
    $content = $header.next();
    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
        $content.slideToggle(200, function () {
            $('.contentCol', this).fadeToggle(400);

    });
});
```

Solved
**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nel_mo/gad27q4b/5/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float:left;` to *.content* to make it keep position on resizing.

```
.content{
   float:left; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gad27q4b/2/

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to the css

```
.header,.content{
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
}
```

Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/gad27q4b/3/

Comment: This works as-well, but @Spokey was a bit quicker on the draw. Up-vote consolation